# Creating a URL from a Javascript button: How to query parameters & parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dictionary, url

This is my JavaScript button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="map.setView({ center : new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.857, 2.333), zoom: 13})" value="Paris"/>
```

I would like to create a URL for this button i.e. GitHub.com/paris.

I have received the following advice:

> If you want a URL to a map on your page you can use query parameters and then parse those and process them as needed.

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I’d recommend using [the second answer by Andy E](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/707111) in the duplicate; the accepted one isn’t very good.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I'm new to this & I can't figure out Andy E's code i.e. where does my onclick function go ... what is my new URL.

Comment: If you `console.log(urlParams);` after including that snippet on a page with query parameters (`https://example.com/your-page?latitude=48.857&longitude=2.333&zoom=13`), you’ll get an idea of the structure you have to work with.